# The reason to use JS .call() method?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, this

I'm interested what's the reason to have call() method in JS. It seems it duplicates usual method of calling `this`.

For example, I have a code with call().

```
var obj = {
    objType: "Dog"
}

f = function(did_what, what) {
    alert(this.objType + " " + did_what + " " + what);
}

f.call(obj, "ate", "food");
```

The output is "Dog ate food". But the same result I can get assigning the function to the object.

```
var obj = {
    objType: "Dog"
}

f = function(did_what, what) {
    alert(this.objType + " " + did_what + " " + what);
}

obj.a = f;
obj.a("ate", "food");
```

The result is the same. But this way is more understandable and convenient to use. Why call() is needed?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to assign the function to an object in all cases. E.g. if you create a function which accepts a callback and you allow also the context to be passed, you *could* assign the callback to the object and call it directly, but which name would you choose? You might override an existing method. `call` provides a simple way to solve that issue.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`call` is used when you want to control the scope that will be used in the function called. You might want the `this` keyword to be something else than the scope you assigned the function to, in those cases you can use `call` or `apply` to call the function with your own scope.

F.ex, it also allows you to call utility methods outside the scope, like when using "private" functions:

```
var obj = (function() {
    var privateFn = function() {
        alert(this.id);
    }
    return {
        id: 123,
        publicFn: function() {
            privateFn.call(this);
        }
    };
}());

obj.publicFn();
```

In the example above, `privateFn` is not exposed in `obj` but it can still be constructed as if it was a part of the public scope (using `this` in the same way).

Comment: But controlling the scope is what bind is for so instead you can do privateFn.bind(this)(); so is call ever necessary or does it just look better?

Comment: @Curtis In this example you have no choice, try substituting the line `publicFn: function()  { ... }` with `publicFn: privateFn.bind(this)`. While you're defining the function, the object you return hasn't been created yet so the context will simply be `window`, as there's no other context at that moment.

Comment: publicFn: function() { privateFn.bind(this)(); } Well you can do this so call doesn't need to exist in javascript since you normally call functions with parenthesis, and call is never necessary.

Comment: @Curtis `bind` creates a new copy of the function while `call` does not. 
Also, `fn.bind(this)('foo')` is a less readable version of `fn.call(this, 'foo')`

Answer (score 49):

**2017 Update**

All functions by way of Function.prototype have the `.call` method. The reason to use `.call()` is to specify what the variable "`this`" refers to.

MDN specifies:

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided individually.

Consider the following:

```
function x() {
    return this;
}

x()
```

In strict mode `x()` returns `undefined` in non strict mode it returns the Global object, `Window` in a browser context.

Example with `.call()` we tell it what "`this`" refers to:

```
function x() {
    return this;
}

var obj = {
    myName      : 'Robert',
    myLocation  : 'Earth'
}

x.call(obj);
```

Result: `{myName: "Robert", myLocation: "Earth"}`. In the above example we are specifying the `obj` object as the value of `this` inside the function `x()`

It can be used to emulate inheritance in OOP.

Example:

```
var Robert = {
    name: "Robert Rocha",
    age: 12,
    height: "5,1",
    sex: "male",
    describe: function() {
        return "This is me " + this.name + " " + this.age + " " + this.height + " " + this.sex;
    }
};
```

Lets say that the above is a master object(prototype) and you want to inherit the function `describe` in another object:

```
var Richard = {
    name: "Richard Sash",
    age: 25,
    height: "6,4",
    sex: "male",
}
```

The `Richard` object does not have the describe function and you want to simply inherit ,so to speak, the function. You would do it like so:

```
console.log( Robert.describe.call( Richard ) );
```

Output: `This is me Richard Sash 25 6,4 male`

Comment: Thanks. ur answer is very easy to understand.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain if there's `this` parameter in the `call` method like: `Robert.describe.call(this,Richard)` . What's the role of `this` here?

Comment: @TomSawyer in this example `this` refers to the current object, the calling object. With `.call()` you can write a method once and inherit it in another object of your choosing without having to write it again, taking care of the DRY principle.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a `Person` object with a prototype function `describe` and then Robert/Richard can be based on this object (i.e. `var Robert = new Person(...);`)... 

I guess you mentioned above that Robert is a master object, so I guess we would use `.call` in places where we need to use a function from another object for another object?

Comment: Great explain! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You would probably use the second way in your example, but sometimes you want to use one object's functions on another object.  An example would be using `Array` methods on Array-like objects like `NodeList`s

```
var el = document.getElementById("foo");
[].forEach.call(el.children, function(child, index) {
    //Iterate over an element's children, performing an action on each one
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's to do with the concept of a [first class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).  Basically languages like Javascript allow you to treat functions as things their own right. Functions can be stored in variables or passed to other functions.

`call()` provides a way to execute a free standing function not attached to any other object.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that please? ("a way to execute a free standing function"). Can we not call the function without `call()`?

Answer (score 1):

After I read this , I understand why.

A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object, then to later call that function and expect it to use the original object as its `this` (e.g., by using the method in callback-based code).

Without special care, however, **the original object is usually lost**. Creating a bound function from the function, using the original object, neatly solves this problem:

```
this.x = 9;    // 'this' refers to global 'window' object here in a browser
const module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() { return this.x; }
};

module.getX();
//  returns 81

const retrieveX = module.getX;
retrieveX();
//  returns 9; the function gets invoked at the global scope

//  Create a new function with 'this' bound to module
//  New programmers might confuse the
//  global variable 'x' with module's property 'x'
const boundGetX = retrieveX.bind(module);
boundGetX();
//  returns 81
```

The origin is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#creating_a_bound_function)