# My first jQuery-based slider, needs some error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am a newbie JS programmer making my own jQuery based slider. Here is what I have done so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="keyVisual">

<p id="loading"><span>Loading Content...</span></p>

<ul id="keySlide">
<li id="slideSplash">SPLASH: no pager control on this slide</li>
<li id="slide01"><a href="http://yahoo.com/"></a></li>
<li id="slide02">
<div class="gchild">
    <p>grand child content, feedly is a google reader alternative you might want to think.    
</p>
    <a href="http://feedly.com/" class="link">feedly</a>
</div>
</li>
<li id="slide03">
<div class="gchild">
<p>some grand child content3</p>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" class="link" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>
</div>
</li>
<li id="slide04">
<div class="gchild">
<p>some grand child content4</p>
<a href="http://google.com" class="link" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="btnMoveNext" class="btnSlide"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></div>
<div id="btnMovePrev" class="btnSlide"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></div>
</div><!-- /#keyVisual -->

<!-- pager -->
<ul id="listTopKey" class="cf">
<li><a href="#slide01" class="no1">No.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide02" class="no2">No.2</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide03" class="no3">No.3</a></li>
<li><a href="#slide04" class="no4">No.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

For JS, please refer to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/B66zk/)

I have one final problem I hope to solve. At the end of the script, I made a function which watches the load status of background images for each slide. When all the BG images are loaded, the slider starts.

This looks fine first time I visit the page but if I click a link to go somewhere, and then come back to this slider page (using browser back button for example), it seems like the slider fails to go on (just stack in loading scene). Most of the time this works fine in both Google Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

I think I need to make some error handling for this situation. I can just think of making a `setTimeout` function to fire `loader();` after maybe 15 seconds. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

P.S. Feel free to customize or implement the code and use it for your own.

Comment: Did you check `complete` property of image before binding load event? Because if your images has already been loaded they will be cached and your event won't trigger

Comment: @ant_Ti I have already used `complete` at line 380 please take a look my  JSFiddle. Doesn't this do the trick?

Comment: You have error there. Will post fix in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is little fix for your code. Also i added error handler.

```
$.each(_imgURLArr, function(i, val) {
    var _tempImg = $('<img/>').attr('src', val),
        handler = function(event) {
            var img = $(this).off('.preloader');

            console.log(val + 'is loaded!', img);
            _imgCounter++;
            console.log('counter is ' + _imgCounter);
            if (_imgCounter == _childL) {
                loader();
            }
        };

    if (_tempImg[0].complete) {
        handler.call(_tempImg[0], {});
    } else {
        _tempImg
            .on('load.preloader', handler)
            .on('error.preloader', function() {
                var img = $(this).off('.preloader');

                console.log('Error loading img', img);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks of correcting my mistake. But I am completely new to `call` method. need some time to understand.

Comment: @norixxx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001830/the-reason-to-use-js-call-method

Comment: @norixxx in two words first argument passed to `call` will be `this` in executed function

Comment: Now I slowly understand the idea but one thing. Why'd you put [0] to _tempImg and why not just _tempImg?

Comment: @norixxx because `_tempImg` is `jQuery` object and `this` in event handler is DOM object. This was made for code consistency.

Comment: i did not know i can retrieve DOM object by putting `[0]` to variable. I think now everything made sense to me :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check how this works in IE8. sometimes I still stack in loading contents... status. nnn...

Comment: OK. here's my test server http://abs.sagamono.com/index_t1.html id and pass (test/test123) test this in Internet Explorer ver.8. click OUTER LINK and come back to slider page. the problem happens let's say 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: never mind for IE8 I think it doesn't work probably because I use IE tester to see the slider. Thank much @ant_Ti.