# Does String(number) call number.toString internally?

Tags: javascript, prototype, tostring

I was just trying something and found this:

If you call `String(n)` inside custom `toString`, it calls itself and throws error `Maximum Call Stack exceeded`,

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4e3baym/1/)

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  return String(this)
}

var a = 10;
try {
  a.toString()
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

but if you call directly `var b = String(a)`, it does not call `toString` function.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4e3baym/)

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function(){
  console.log(this);
  return '' + this;
}

var a = 10;
a.toString();
```

**Note:** I know above snippet is also throwing same error, but I have checked on `Node`, `chrome - JSFiddle` and `Firefox - JSFiddle` and it is consistent. `var b = String(a)` does not call `number.toString()`, so does `'' +  this`. This is some optimisation in Stack snippet thats calling `number.toString()` on `''+this`.

So my question is, what am I missing? Why is this weird behaviour?

Comment: @Downvoters, I respect you perspective, but if you think, something is wrong with the post, please share your comment. Just voting it down will not help anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual numbers invoke an internal method to convert them to string and their output is not affected by `valueOf` and `toString`, unless they are called explicitly.

So why is `toString` called in the first place then?

This is because in "sloppy" (non-strict) mode, the value of `this` will be converted to its object form (i.e. equivalent of `new Number(10)`) before being passed to `String(this)` or `'' + this`.

(For this reason, you might not see the difference between these two ways in normal applications where strict mode is used.)

As `this` is an object, both `String()` and the `+` addition operator will attempt to convert the object into a string. This is usually done by calling either `obj.toString` or `obj.valueOf`.

As for why `String(this)` fails but `'' + this` does not, the `String` function calls `toString` on the object before calling `valueOf`.

However, when you use the addition (`+`) operator, the order of `valueOf` and `toString` is reversed.

Comment: Not sure about "*the value of this will be converted to its object form…*. I think it's the second part, `String(value)` will call `value.toString`, so if its *toString* method than calls *String*, recursion occurs. See [*ECMA-262 §21.1.1.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string-constructor-string-value).

Comment: @RobG: what I meant was that the reason `toString` is called in the first place is that `String()` on the object form of the number. I'll try and clarify what I've said.

Comment: Cool. Actually, reading more closely, ECMA-262 doesn't specify calling toString in the [*algorithm for ToString(number)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type), it might just be how it's implemented.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy You are correct. A small query though, in second approach, `'' + this`, in `non strict mode`, `this` should be interpreted as `new Number(10)`. right?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Then why does `''+this` works but `String(this)` doesn't

Comment: @Rajesh: see last sentence. As `valueOf` has not been overridden, that will return the number primitive `10`, which is then converted using internal algorithm to string.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use call/apply.

```js
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log(this)
  return String(this)
}

var a = 10;
try {
  a.toString.call()
  console.log(a)
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

reason I think is [The reason to use JS .call() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001830/the-reason-to-use-js-call-method)

Comment: Hey, objective of question is understanding why this is happening. Also just a pointer, doing `.call` without `this` will erase context.