# Pseudo array arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

I learn js and now I am learning prototypes. I found this code:

```
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Could you tell me what does mean `0` here. I saw the code with `(arguments, 1)` and did not understand.Could you help me in this question? Thanks.

Comment: check documentation of `slice` and then its first argument, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: This code is outdated, and won't help you with "learning prototypes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you've become confused by the `arguments` variable and `call()` function.

- `arguments` is a `hidden` variable which [any function has](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp).
- `call` is a function to send a context of execution to a function. [Read great answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001830/the-reason-to-use-js-call-method)

Try to debug and all becomes more clearer:

```
function list() {
  console.log('Function hidden args: ', arguments)// Output: Function hidden args: [1, 2, 
      //3, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
}
var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

So this `return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);` can be converted to

```
[/*array items here*/].slice(0)
```

`0` means here a starting point from existing array where new array will be created.
For example:

```
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].slice(1)); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].slice(2)); // [3, 4, 5]
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].slice(3)); // [4, 5]
```

Comment: @AsasSas I am glad that it helped to you!:)

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) `Array.prototype.slice` expects at least one argument, `start`, which is the position at which to start "slicing".
You would call this method like this: `[1, 2, 3].slice(0)` and you'd get a *copy* of the array, with the same elements.

`method.call` is a way to call a method of an object and specify the `this` (the object itself) as an argument (documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). So instead of `[1, 2, 3].slice(0)` you can do `Array.prototype.slice.call([1, 2, 3], 0)`, where `[1, 2, 3]` will be `this` inside `Array.prototype.slice`, meaning the array instance it acts upon, all subsequent parameters (`0` in this case) are passed to the called function.

`arguments` is a "magic" variable inside any function that is an `array` of all the arguments passed to the function. Note that in JavaScript you *can* call a function with any number of extra arguments. In your case `arguments` will be `[1, 2, 3]`.

So to answer your initial question: `0` is the position at which to start the "slicing".

Comment: Very good answer however I like to motivate people reading the documentation. Because the Mozilla documentation is already fantastic and very good understandable plus it gives good examples.

Comment: Me too. In this case I considered a bigger push would be helpful though :) More links = more _guided_ reading material IMHO.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right ;), I hope your work is honored!

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls the function `slice()` with the parameter `0`. Please also take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more information on call and what it does I'm not going to reiterate the functionality here. Furthermore I suggest the `slice()` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). In your case `slice(0)` does "nothing" because a copy of the original array is returned. The call `slice(1)` would return all elements except the first one.

Comment: @PranavCBalan you are right a mistake in writing it fast, I'm aware of that.